# How to let a user draw a figure in a GUI in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i’m implementing a basic discrete crowd dynamics software, where a number of people can move in a pre-defined area, avoiding obstacles and looking for the exits. Right now, I manually construct the area with the below function, that takes as input `(_xMax, _yMax)`, the dimension of the area in terms of unit cells. Given the dimensions, the function builds up two 2D arrays (which I handle as 1D): `arena_type[]`, that, for each cell, holds a number indicating the cell type (-1: the cell is an obstacle; 0: the cell is empty; 1: the cell is an exit); `arena_shape[]`, that, for each cell, holds a char indicating the char to draw when the arena is printed in stdout or to a file.

```
def build_arena(_xMax, _yMax):

    xmax = int(_xMax)
    ymax = int(_yMax)

    arena_type = [0 for xx in range(xmax*ymax)]
    arena_shape = [0 for xx in range(xmax*ymax)]

    for i in range(0, ymax):
        for j in range(0, xmax):
            arena_type[j + xmax * i] = 0
            arena_shape[j + xmax * i] = 0

            if (i == 0):
                if j<4 or j>4:
                    arena_shape[j + xmax * i] = "-"
                    arena_type[j + xmax * i] = -1
                    sys.stdout.write("-")
                else:
                    arena_shape[j + xmax * i] = " "
                    arena_type[j + xmax * i] = 2
                    sys.stdout.write(" ")
            elif i == (ymax-1):
                arena_shape[j + xmax * i] = "-"
                arena_type[j + xmax * i] = -1
                sys.stdout.write("-")
            elif j == 0:
                if i<4 or i>4:
                    arena_shape[ j + xmax * i ] = "|"
                    arena_type[ j + xmax * i ] = -1
                    sys.stdout.write("|")
                else:
                    arena_shape[j + xmax * i] = " "
                    arena_type[j + xmax * i] = 1
                    sys.stdout.write(" ")
            elif j==xmax-1:
                arena_shape[j + xmax * i] = "|"
                arena_type[j + xmax * i] = -1
                sys.stdout.write("|")
            else:
                arena_shape[j + xmax * i] = " "
                sys.stdout.write(" ")

    return arena_type, arena_shape
```

My goal now is to substitute this function with a GUI where the user can draw a custom area on a grid of cells. This GUI shall return back to the program this grid together with the informations I need (shape and type, to be inferred in some ways from the drawn area). I went through some Python GUI libraries (such as Tkinter), but I could not find how to let the user build up the area directly from the GUI window. I could only find how to draw a program-side area in an external window.

Any insights is really appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT 1: grid of buttons (as suggested by Bryan Oakley)

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid()

grid = Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W, column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)

for x in range(60):
    for y in range(30):
        btn = Button(grid)
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can't you just draw a grid of buttons or labels, and let the user click on each one individually to define what type of cell it is?

Comment: @BryanOakley: thank you for your insight. I tried to build a grid of buttons, it displays nicely but it is really demanding in terms of performance, and there is not yet any code attached to it.. Am I doing anything wrong? Back to the original question (drawable GUI interface), am I looking for a user-interface that is very hard to build?